# The distribution of sum of two binomials with complement success probabilities

Tags: binomial-coefficients

It is well-known that if $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* binomial random variables with parameters $(n_1,p)$ and $(n_2,p)$ respectively, $Z = X+Y$ has a binomial distribution with with parameters $(n_1+n_2,p)$.

I was wondering if $Y$ is binomial with parameters $(n_2, 1-p)$ what will be the distribution of $X+Y$?

Comment: Your first statement is true if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and not if they're not.  The answer to the question at the end also depends on information about the joint distribution that you've omitted.  If, for example, $Y$ is simply $n_1-X$, then $X+Y$ would be a constant, equal to $n_1$.  But if they're independent (the opposite extreme) then the distribution of the sum would be non-trivial. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You are right, I should have explicitly mentioned that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I'll correct the question.